# Trouble publishing using clickonce to ftp server running filezilla

Tags: c#, ftp, clickonce, publishing

I'm trying to publish a C# application using ClickOnce to an ftp server running Filezilla. I have taken care of port forwarding and firewall exceptions.

I can publish fine from the server itself, but when I try to publish from a different PC on a different network, it doesn't work.

I have tried both passive and active ftp modes, and it doesn't work with either of them.  Active mode gives error 425 (can't open data channel).

Comment: Does the error give you any further information?  Does the publish work from any machine?  Are you running the FileZilla server yourself?  Are the computers you're trying to publish from running on the same network as the server?  What do you mean by "passive" and "active" mode?  Have you tried things like this article: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Setting_up_your_Router_to_Fix_the_%22425_code%22

Comment: you can publish to a local folder and copy the output manually (or by some process other than the ClickOnce wizard) to wherever you want, if that helps.

Comment: @Taegost The error doesn't give any information, the publish works on the same machine as the server, I'm running it myself, the pc's aren't on the same network, passive and active are both ftp transfer modes and yes.

Comment: @DrewJordan Thanks, but I really want this to work (:

Comment: Can the computer you're trying to publish from access the FTP server at all?  What happens if you try to publish from another computer within the same network?  Also, it would behoove you to update the question with the information you're giving in the comments as it will help other give more informed responses.

Comment: I've used ClickOnce a lot in the past, but never come across using FTP as the transport medium. To satisfy my curiosity I googled it and was suprised to find it is a use-case with some history. I dont have an answer myself but you might try reviewing the links here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/61ffaf54-1696-469a-9184-2c4287b3ea86/publishing-application-with-clickonce-to-ftp-and-installing?forum=winformssetup to see if they lead you to a solution, since the authors claim to have done it.